# VS 2013 WCF Service Library missing

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013

Quick question

I am doing a Plural Sight tutorial on WCF and they are using the WCF Service Library (as opposed to application.)

When I go to Add new project there is no WCF Service Library. Not under any of the .NET versions.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for Web Express.

Any one know how I can get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under Templates WCF. 
( Go to New Project->Installed-->Templates-->WCF)

Comment: Thats the problem. It isn't there. I just have WCF Service Application there.

Comment: I can't find the devenv. I think the layout is different for VS2013 for web.